# Replace (.) in ToC with a space

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, appendices

I am creating my own Appendix numbering in a document, and the number isn't appearing correctly in the ToC. In `appendixa.tex`, I have:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix \Alph{section}}

\section{}
\label{s:appa}
```

This creates a new section called "Appendix A", and any references in the document appear as "Appendix A". My issue is, in the ToC, it appears as "Appendix.A". Is there any simple way to change this so it appears as "Appendix A" in the ToC?

****EDIT****

This is my main document, `report.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

%% =========

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

%% =========

\input intro
\setcounter{section}{1}

%% intro.tex is a separate file with only a section, and there are more
%% \input lines after this. They all appear in the documents and ToC
%% correctly. Each is simply a section. This can be commented out.

\afterpage{\clearpage}

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
%% =========
\bibliography{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}

\newpage
\setcounter{section}{0}

\input appendixa

\newpage
\endpage

\end{document}
```

My entire `appendixa.tex` file is above.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide us with a compilable document to reproduce the error? (Something we can copy paste.)

Comment: @Zach You can edit your question.  But your sample won't really help as it is, since you are using `\input`. But this shouldn't be necessary for showing the problem. (and you have some extra stuff that's not relevant either) Just use some dummy text instead.

Comment: Your code is quite strange, i recommend reading [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html). :-)

Comment: On a different and off topic matter: Is your audience used to documents with appendices? The mere change of numbering is usually enough for the reader to say *Oh, something happened, this is the appendix* This is especially the case, when the document had a nice *conclusion* or *summary* right before it ;-)

Comment: Yes, they are. My issue is just how it appears in the ToC. I do not want it to say "A   (Name)", I want it to say "Appendix A". Right now it appears as "Appendix.A". I'm just attempting to replace the "." with a space.

Comment: Honestly I think you are doing most of this in the wrong way, and answering the question you ask isn't actually going to be the right way to solve the problem. I would recommend using a document class like `memoir` or one of the KOMA classes which provide builtin hooks for doing most of this kind of thing and are very well documented.  It will make your like much easier in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is that the O.P. does not use the `\appendix` command at all and confuses `chapter` and `section` throughout the whole document.

Now redefinition of `\thesection` as `{Appendix \Alph{section}}` will lead to a very wide section number -- too wide for the `ToC` number region -- it leaks into the dotted section line, that is why a dot **`.`** appears there.

If the class is `book` or `report` → the main appendix unit is `\chapter`, if the class is `article` the appendix unit is `section`.

Mixing it is not recommended (as well as not giving a title -- from a typographical/informational point of view)

I changed some settings and used `appendix` package with the `title,titletoc` options. This will automatically provide the `Appendix ...` entry in the title as well as in the `ToC`

For the `bibliography` inclusion in `ToC` I used `tocbibind`

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{report}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}


\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\title{Theory of Brontosaurs}
\author{Ann Elk (Misses)}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty} %%%
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

%% =========


\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1} % Useless
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

%% =========

%\input intro
% \setcounter{section}{1}
\section{Intro}
\cite{Lam94}

%% intro.tex is a separate file with only a section, and there are more
%% \input lines after this. They all appear in the documents and ToC
%% correctly. Each is simply a section. This can be commented out.

%% =========


\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{biblio}




\begin{appendices}

\chapter{}\label{c:appa} 

\blindtext[5]
\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

[image]